# Vagrant fails to provision docker container

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-plugin

My Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.add_recipe "tomcat"
end
config.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
  docker.create_args = ["-d"]
  docker.has_ssh = true
end
config.ssh.port = 22
config.ssh.username = "root"
config.ssh.password = "password"

end
```

and Dockerfile:

```
FROM precise-prepared
##ADD SCRIPTS IN DOCKER IMAGE
ADD ssh.sh /ssh.sh
RUN chmod +x /ssh.sh
RUN echo "root:password" | chpasswd
EXPOSE 22
##START ssh services during startup
CMD ["/ssh.sh"]
```

precise-prepared is just a slightly modified ubuntu:12.04 docker image.

When I'm running vagrant up command it fails with the following error:

> Vagrant attempted to execute the capability 'chef_install' on the
>   detect guest OS 'linux', but the guest doesn't support that
>   capability. This capability is required for your configuration of
>   Vagrant. Please either reconfigure Vagrant to avoid this capability or
>   fix the issue by creating the capability.

Is it vagrant's docker provider doesn't support provisioning with chef or I am missing something?

Thanks